# unable to get the output of an eval JS script

Tags: javascript, python, eval

I am trying to get the output of a java script code outside of the browser, using node command line or nodejs command line or any python script, here is the script:

```
;eval(function(k,i,s,e){var lIll=0;var ll1I=0;var Il1l=0;var ll1l=[];var l1lI=[];while(true){if(lIll<5)l1lI.push(k.charAt(lIll));else if(lIll<k.length)ll1l.push(k.charAt(lIll));lIll++;if(ll1I<5)l1lI.push(i.charAt(ll1I));else if(ll1I<i.length)ll1l.push(i.charAt(ll1I));ll1I++;if(Il1l<5)l1lI.push(s.charAt(Il1l));else if(Il1l<s.length)ll1l.push(s.charAt(Il1l));Il1l++;if(k.length+i.length+s.length+e.length==ll1l.length+l1lI.length+e.length)break;}var lI1l=ll1l.join('');var I1lI=l1lI.join('');ll1I=0;var l1ll=[];for(lIll=0;lIll<ll1l.length;lIll+=2){var ll11=-1;if(I1lI.charCodeAt(ll1I)%2)ll11=1;l1ll.push(String.fromCharCode(parseInt(lI1l.substr(lIll,2),36)-ll11));ll1I++;if(ll1I>=l1lI.length)ll1I=0;}return l1ll.join('');}('a60e41s212829333718243q013z1o25312q193x2c1d3q0z112k3q01302m3v3u37242v203p11303a231s27332114212x23211y3u291z1138251s25352z1622361y1z12161z153v2b2q1721241u3u2t212n113w242e133x2b2o192z2611101o233e1i3c2b36182x3s121z1o280w121z3b233v212938182v3u10111o3c182t3b233v2b213x3b213x29233x1z112s2911302u271u2u271r2o1i27302q2c1z23121b3v111130243316212o1b3v111k1t352z1d223n2e1z3w2o2z1q1e27211o1o23111s253t173126142e1c3e2b361c3w2b341v3w2s3q3u3722293r3730291716211411101o253c1q1z113w242e1b373a3v111x23141g1d1o1a3f1i1f1h1f1j3c181c1v3e1a1g193f143e1m3e1m1e1u1g101f172c1t2c122e1s2e1x2e1t2d1u2c1u1e1r2e1r2g1y2c1u2c172e1r3g1s2e1u2c1k2c1w1e1x2e1s1e1x2c1s2d1y2e1r2e1r2e1s2d172c1v2e1s2e1q2e1e2c1u2e1v2e1s2g1p2e1s3e1x2c1u2g122e1s2g1y2c1t2e112e1q1e1q2e1s2e1v2c1v2e1t2e1r2e1v2c1s3d1y2e1s2e1o2e1s3e1h2c1u2f172e1q3f102c1s2d1a2e1q3f162e1s1d172c1u3g1y2e1q3f172c1u3d1w2e1q3f172e1s3d1t2c1u2f152e1s3f1v2c1s3d1b2e1r3e1a2e1s3d182c1w3f1w2e1q3f192c1u3d1a2e1q3f172e1u3d1e2c1u3f152e1q3g1r2c1s2d1b2e1q3f1a2e1s3d192c1u3g1u2e1q1f172c1s3d1b2e1q3f152e1s3d1b2c1u2e1s2e1q1e1f1c1b1d1g3g1a1e1g1g1m3d1r3b1e3f1d3f1g2f123d1l2d1e2g1k1e193e1f3d1c3d1r1g1d1g1c3g1f1c1f1d1e3e1b1f141g1s1d1b1d1e3f1d3g1e3f1g2c1f1c1f3e1d1g1k3e1f1c183d153g1f2e191f1k1d1d3c1i3g1h3g1h3g1j1e143d1g3g1k1g1k1g1i1e1b2c1e1g1f3d1b2f1c1c1s2e1e3f1d3f103e1f3d1f3c1r3g1j3e1b3g181d1d3c143e191f171f1f1d1d1d1l1g1d2e1j2e1f1c1f1c1f3f1d1e161d1f1e1h1c1t2e1q2g1t2e1t2e1t2c1w2g1r2e1s2g1w2c1s2c1v2e1q2e1h2e1s1c142c1v1g1u2e1s2g1i2c1s2c1h2f1q2g1p2e1u3e152c1v2f1t2e1s1f1t2c1s2e1j2e1s1g1r2e1u2e1r2c1v1g1w2e1s3e1t2c1t3d1k1e1s2f1q2e1s2c1v2c1w1g142e1r3e1r2c1u1e1u2e1r2e1p2e1t2d1v2c1w2g1p2e1s3e1j2c1t2e1f2e1d3f1r3e1v2d1r3c14142b123c181e1i3g1e2g1e3d142c1k3f181g1e1f1d2e1j1c143g1a1e1p3g162c1u2e1t2e1q2e1x2e1w2c1g2c1v3e1r2e1s2g1y2c1t2c1v2e1s2g1e2e1v2c1x2c1w2g1w2e1s2e1a2c1s2e1z2e1s2g192e1u1d162c1u2e1x2e1q1g1i2c1u1c1w2e1r2e1i2e1w2c162c1u2g1k2e1q1f1b2c1u2e1r2e1s2g1v2e1u2e1y2c1u2f1y2e1q2e1y2c1s1d1m2e1p2g1t2e1v3e1g2c1u1f172e1s3f1a2c1s3d1b2e1s3g142e1u1d172c1w3f1a2e1q2f192c1u3d1i2e1q3f172e1w3d1d2c1u3f162e1s3g1d2c1s3d192e1q3f152e1u2d172c1w3e182e1q3f1a2c1s3e1c2e1q3f162e1u3d1a2c1u1f152e1r3f1d2c1s3d1b2e1q3f132e1u2d172c1w3g1u2e1q1f192c1s3d1d2e1q1f152e1u3c1z2c1u2e1u2e1i1e143d1l1e1m1f121g101f162e1s2e1e3f121g1y3f1k1d1d3c1f1f141g1d1f1d1d1e3d1e3g1e3f1e3e1f1c1f1c1e1g1k3e1d1e1a3e133e1j2e192f1i3f1e1c1g2c1u1g1h3g1b3e1l3c1f1d1d3f1h1f161e142c191d1d1f192f191f1d1c181c1f3f163f133e1k1e1s3d1h1g1d1g1d1e1e3c1b3c1b1f1p1g1q3g141c1u1e163f1d3f151f1j1e1s2e1l2g1k1e183g1a1e1m3e1f1e1f1e1d1e1i2c1f3e1j2e1g2g1d3f1h2c181e1a2e1s1g1q2e1v3e142c1u2g1s2e1r2e1v2c1t3c182e1s1e1u2e1w1e1r2c1w2e1k2e1r3e1s2c1k2c1r2e1r3e142e1w2e1u2c1t2f1w2e1q2g1x2c1u2e1r2e1q1e1y2e1t2c1w2c1w3e1y2e1q1g102c1r1c1w2e1q1g1t2e1w3c1u2c1w2g1r2e1q3e172c1t2d1y2e1s2e1i2e1u2e1l2c1t2e1k2e1r1f1k2c1t2e1m2e1t3f1y2e103d1h121g1f1g1g1e3g1w1e1j2d1d1e1j1f171f1h1d1d1c1l1e1u1g1j3e1u3d1e2c1u1e1i2e1q2e112c1u2c1x2e1u1g1p2e1v1c1g2c1u1f1x2e1r2e1r2c1u1e1x2e1t2e1r2e1w3c1y2c1u3e1e2e1s2e1t2c1s1d182e1s2e1s2e1u2e1k2c1v2e1z2e1r2g102c1t2c102e1s2f1i2e1u3c182c1u3e1r2e1s2e1s2c1t1c1i2e1u2e122e1w2c1z2c1u2e1b2e1s2g1g2c1t3e1l2e1s2f162e1u3c1f2c1u3f192e1q3f1d2c1s3d1a2e1t3e172e1u3d172c1u3e182e1q2f1a2c1u3c1f2e1s1f172e1u3c1h2c1u3f182e1s3f1b2c1s3d1b2e1s3e1x2e1u2d192c1u3f1b2e1q1f1b2c1s3d1e2e1s1f152e1v3e1b2c1u2f182e1q3f1a2c1s2d192e1t3e1h2e1u3d182c1u3f192e1q3f192c1s3d1v2e1s2e1s2e1h1c1f3b163g1f1f161g1e2e1f1c1k3g1p3f1w1g1e3c1f1e1e3g1h1e191f1m1d183d1f3e1a1f1e3f161d1h1d141g1w2f1h3f1a1c121b1e1f1e3f1k1e1d3c1d3d1l3f131f1j1e1k1d1h1d1i2e181e1d1f181e1s1d1l3e181e161e1a1c181c1u3g1j1e181e1c1e123b1e3g1c1e1g2f1e3d1f1c141g143g1b3e1e1d1e3d1l1g1c2e172f161d1f1c1e3e1c2f1g3f1c1e1g1d1e3g1k1f1f2e1u3d1j3d172f1e3f122f1g2d1c1c1h2e1t2e1s1e1s2c1s2c1v2e1s3g1j2e1t3c1v2c1v2g1w2e1q3g122c1t2d1l2e1u1e1u2e1w2e1u2c1u1e102e1s2e1v2c1u2d1j2e1u3e142e1t3e1h2c1t2g1t2e1p2e1x2c1s2e1z2e1r3e1x2e1v2c1l2c1u2g1k3e1r2e1l2c1t3c1w2e1t2f1r2e1v1e102c1u2g1a2e1s2g1w2c1s3c1t2e1t2g1s2e1w3e152c1w2f1t1e1u2e1b2c1u3c191e121u2j1f1q1r1h1c2d1d1q141m','27835o3o1t3s2210271s3b3v211b3o01101o252z3q193x2c1i1b3v111i1a21173u3w1z311411133v3b2o1920341u3s2v203n113u262c133x292q1730361z311m233e1g3e29361y2v3u1z101o260y1z102b213x2z39381w2x3s1z121m3e162t212n112038251q27333c162z2x233c182s291z1z3a231s25333e1421261w102s291w3s29163u271s3u271q2c1z3w26111z3u281z3w243s3o3o011z3z3b3w141m252e2o111x21141z121m253e2o2o35303q1z312z39233v3226143q0z1e1c2t2e292q122s11101f2z1o112z3a23353w253w253r1536231z1z3a37112z141j1z1e1m3c182t312p3c2b213x2z2o1i27332c393y121o121c1e1d1f1c1c1h1c143e1i1e1a2g1k1c1a3e1a1e131g1i1e1i1d1f2c1u1d1p2e1r2g1r2c1s2c1y2c1q2g1c2e1s1c1z2c1u3c1p2e1s2e122c1s2e1r2c1s1e1i2e1r3c1h2c1w2d1x2e1q3e1x2c1t1d1w2c1q1f1s2e1q2c1u2c1v3e1t2e1s2e1t2c1u2e1b2c1s1f1w2e1r2e1q2c1u2d1w2e1r2g1j2c1t1c1w2c1r2e1q2e1q3c1y2c1u3c172e1s2g1y2c1s3c192c1r3g1r2e1q2d172c1u3d1v2e1q3f152c1s3d1d2c1q2f172e1q3d1a2c1u1d172e1s3g142c1s3d1a2c1q3f1t2e1q2d172c1v3e1a2e1q3f162c1s3d162c1q3f172e1s3d1a2c1u3d162e1q3f162c1s3d1b2c1q3f1b2e1q3d172c1u3d1r2e1q2f172c1s3d182c1q3f152e1r3c1i2c1u2d152e1q3g172c1s3d192c1s2e1s2e1q2c1e1c1h1c1k1g1a1e1i2d1d3c1d2c121e101g123d1s3d1e1e1s1f1u2f1h1d183d141b1d3f1c3g1k1c1b3c1e3d1h3f113g1j1c1i1d1j3d1e2e161e1d2d161e1u1e1h3e1d1e1e3e141d1j3e173f1d3f1q1e1m3c1e1c1d3f1d3f1d3d1f3d1e3d1d1f192f1c3d1e3d1d1e1q3e1d1e121d1s1e1h3e1p3d1d3f1d1c1f3c1a1c1d2g192e1a1d1b3d1i2c1d2e1d1g1i1c1d3c1i1d1e2e1h1f1r2c1s1d1l3c1b3f161e1b3e1i3d1h1c1e3f1p3f1q2c1u2c1v2c1s1f1r2e1s1c1t2c1u1e1t2e1r2f1u2c1u2c1h2c1s1g1j2e1s3e1v2c1w2e1r2e1y3g1q2c1u2d172c1s3e1p2e1r3c1l2c1w2c1r2e1q1g1j2c1t2c1q2c1r3e1k2e1p1c102c1v3c162e1d2e1u2c1u3c1y2c1s2e1j2e1p1e152c1t2d1f2e1q1e1w2c1u2e1w2c1r2g1r2e1r2e102c1w3e1r2e1r2e163c143c1u2c141e171t1j123g1d3f183e1r3c1c3c1s3g181g1i3c1j1c1q1c1f2e161d1g3d142c1w2e1r2e1s2g1r2c1s3e1z2c1q3g122e1u2e1y2c1v2e1x2e1q1e1s2c1s2e1x2c1r2e1t2e1t3c1v2c1u3d1u2e1s3e1q2c1s3e1j2c1q3e1x2e1s2c1e2c1u1c1g2e1q2e1z2c1u1c1x2c1s1g1p2e1t1c1g2c1u1d1v2e1r2e1p2c1u1e1x2c1r2e1r2e1u3c1y2c1u3c1c2e1s2e1r2c1s1d182c1s3e1e2e1s3d192c1w3d142e1q3f172c1s3d1d2c1q2f172e1s3d1v2c1u3d162e1q3e182c1s3d1b2c1s3g192e1s3d182c1u3d162e1q3f192c1u3d1x2c1q3f162e1s3c1c2c1u3d172e1s3g1d2c1s3d1b2c1q3g1i2e1s2d172c1w3e1a2e1q3f192c1u3c1s2c1q1f152e1t3c1i2c1u3d152e1q3f1b2c1s3d192c1q3e1x2e1s1c1k1c1a3d1i1g1h1g1c1c1i3d1r3d1p3d1d3g1c1d1b3e1j3d111g1j1e1i1d1h3d1i3c161e1d1f161e1f1e1l3c1b1e1e3f141e1h3e1b3d1d3f1q1g1p3c1f1c1f3d1q2g1k1e1b3c1f3e1e1c1k1g1d1g1j3e1d3c1u1d1k1g1k1g1p1e1m1e1e3d1i1g161e181c142d1f3d1b1e1k3e1c1d1g1e161e1d3e1e3e1d3e1f3d1e3c1g1e101e161e1k3d1j2c1q2g1o3f1f3e183e1m1d131g1i1e1c1c1d3d1u3c1d3f1q2g1o3c1d1c1y2c1d2e1r1g1k2c1t1c102c1q2f1q2e1s2d1t2c1u2c182e1s2f1j2c1u2c1j2c1s1g1p2e1t2c1d2c1w2c1x3e1s1g152c1u1e1z2c1q3e1q2e1t3d1v2c1u1c1w2e1s2e1f2c1u1c1w2c1s1e152e1s3e1j2c1v3c1d1e1r3e1j2c1t2d122c1s1e1r2e1u2e162c1v1c1r2e1s2e1y2c1t3c1q2c1q2e1s2e1t3d1k2c1u1e1w2e1q3e102c1x3d112c172e1h1f1e3e1c1c1k3c1p1g1h1f1k1c1d3c1i1d1g1f1e2e1h1e1b2c172c1u1e1j2e1t2c1t2c1u1c1o2e1q3g1f2c1u2c1g2c1s3g1e2e1u2d1x2c1v2e1j2e1s2g1t2c1u3e112c1s2e1a2e1u1c1x2c1w2c1h2e1q1e1u2c1s2c1y2c1t2e1y2e1u2c1z2c1v2d1u2e1q1e1t2c1t2e102c1u2e132e1t3e1u2c1w1c1k2e1s1e1z2c1u1c1z2c1s3f1u2e1t3c1t2c1u2d172e1r3e1z2c1s3d1a2c1s3e1c2e1s3d182c1w3e1d2e1q3f182c1s3d1f2c1s2f152e1t3d1z2c1u3d172e1q3e1k2c1s3d192c1s3f142e1s1d192c1u3d152e1q3f182c1s3d1x2c1s3f172e1s3d1g2c1u2d192e1q3f1b2c1s1d192c1s3e1o2e1s1d192c1w3d1t2e1q3f182c1u3e102c1s3f152e1s3d192c1u3d172e1q2e1u2c1s2e1h1c123g173f1b1c1m3d1t3b1d3f1d3e1b2c1m3c102d1k3g1d3e1c1e1m3c1f1c183f113g1h2c1b2d1m1e1c1e1e2e1s2e1c3e1e1c1j3e1b1f1b1d1j3d1a3c122e173f1c1e1g3d1i2c1c3f1q1f1k1c1l1c1k1e1h1f1a3f1k3d1k1d1m3e1k3f1d3f1c1e1j1e1j3e141e1d1g1f3d1s3c1f1c1c1e1g2f121d141d1e1d1b1f1f3d1s2d1s2d1h3c1d2f123f1o1e1a1e1k3c1j1e1d1g1c1c1x1c142c191f1q1f1b1d1w1e1u1e1f3e1y2e1u2c1j2c1u1c1y2e1p3g162c1t3e1a2c1t1e1y2e1t2c1c2c1v2e1z2e1r2g1d2c1u2c1t2c1s2g1d2e1u2c1s2c1u1d1q2e1r1g102c1s2e172c1s2g1r2e1u3e1v2c1w2e1y2e1p2g102c1u1c1q2c1t2f1p2e103c1s2c1v1c162e1s1g1u2c1s2d1l2c1u2g1u2e1u2c1u2c1w3c102e1q2g1x2c1s2c182c1u3g1r2e1f3d1v2d1t3c163f1f192c1p1h1k2g1k2h1q2i1l2c14','2a7472935333w351w391g25322o1b3x3c1d3o02111m272z3q2o253e2o2o2y233a1e25211g3e2938102v3u1z311o360y1z312b213x2z3b381y2x3s11211m21162v212n11203a251q27333e162z2x233e1y3s291z113a231s25352e1431261y121z161z153x392q1721261s3u2t212p1z3w243e153v3b2o192134121z1o251z3w26113w26113u28113u2q2z3b233v3e29233x29233v2720393x2c11112235143q02303e293y141m3e1b3q013z2m2211211m211z112u27112z1f3b3v3e181y12302x3u2u353c121z1e1o1z153v29231t322o14252522332e1826352z1f1g183e1431281w111011223s291z121o3s370z31243316331f2l3d1l1e1m1f1d1e1c3f1j2e1q3d1h3g163g1i1g1i1c1h2d1g3e1q3f1i2e1t3c1z2c1v2g1w2e1r2e1y2c1s2d1m2e1q2e162e1s3c1r2c1w2e1o2e1r1e1g2c1u2c162e1s2e1x2e1s2c1b2c1w2g1c2e1r3g1j2c1s2c1w2e1q1g122e1u2e1r2c1u2e1x2e1s2e1g2c1t3c1v2e1s2g1u2e1t3c1t2c1w2g1e2e1r2e1x2c1u2e102e1s2e162e1s2e1x2c1w2g192e1q1f162c1u3e1x2e1q3f172e1s3d192c1u3f162e1q3g1z2c1s2d1b2e1q3e1g2e1s2d172c1w3f122e1q2f172c1t3d1q2e1q2f172e1u3d142c1u3f172e1s3e1c2c1s2d192e1s3f1b2e1s3d172c1v3f1d2e1q3f172c1s3e1d2e1q2f152e1t3d1z2c1u3f142e1s3g1a2c1s2d1a2e1s3g1t2e1s3d172c1u3g172e1q3f1u2c1s2c1w2e1d1e1f3f1g1e1g3e1w1g121g1q2g1d1c1i3d141g123f1e1e1g1c1s1e1d3g1d3e1h3e1f2d1b3d1l3f163f103e191d1f1e1i3f1e2e1d3f1s3d1k3c1q1e1g1f1f3f1c1c1h3c1d1f1i3f163f1f3c1a1d1i3g121f1f1e121c1a1c1c1e181e183g1m1e1s1d1d1f191f1k3f1f1d1g1e1f1g1k3e102e141d101c1e3f1d3f1i3g1t2e1s1c1f1f183g1q1e1s3c1g3d1g3g121f1g1g1s1d1g3c1w1g1f3f1a3e1f1d1k3c143g1d3f1e1g172e182c1u2g1r2e1s2e1j2c1u2c1h2e1q2g1k2e1u2d1r2c1u1g1o2e1s3g1j2c1s2e162e1r1f1r2e1s1c152c1v2f1o2e1s3e152c1r2c1a2e1s2e1r2e1s1c1f2c1w2g1p2e1r2e152c1u2d1j2e1r2g142e1u1e1v2c1u2g162e1s2e1t2c1t3e1j2e1r2f1v2e1t2c1l2c1t2e1v2e1r2g1y2c1t2c1v2e1q1g142e1t3c1x1c112e152e1p2e1f321k1f3g1b3d1e1c1b1e111g103e161e1i3d191g1c1g1i1e1z3e1i3e172e1r3g1t2e1w2c1v2c1w2g172e1s1f102c1t2e1s2e1q2f1w2e1v2e1l2c1v1e1s2e1r2e1u2c1s2c102e1q3e172e1w2e102c1u3e152e1r3g112c1s2c1y2e1s1e1j2e1v2c1t2c1u1e1j2e1q3g1h2c1u1c1g2e1q3g1e2e1w2d1x2c1v2g1h2e1s2g1v2c1u2e112e1q2e1a2e1w1c1x2c1w2e1f2e1q1f1a2c1u3d1c2e1q3f172e1u3d1a2c1u3f172e1s3f1q2c1s3d1b2e1r3e1b2e1u1d182c1w3f132e1q3f192c1t3d1f2e1q1f162e1w3e102c1u3f162e1q3f1b2c1s3d1a2e1q3e152e1u3d172c1u3e1b2e1q3f192c1s3e1q2e1q3f172e1w3e1f2c1u3f152e1q3f1l2c1s2d1a2e1s3f1c2e1u1d172c1u3f192e1q2e112c1s2c1m1e1f3e1d1f1g1c1h3b1e3f1d3e192e161c103b1f2g161f171f1e1e1g3d1i3e1d3f1d3f1m1c1l1c1k1f1f1g1a3e1j1c1b1d1m3f163f1d3e1c1e1g3d161f1f1e101f1y2d1j1d1a1e101d1b3g1g3e1m1c1d3e1d3g1h3f1g3d1e3e1g3f1c3e1d3f1e1e1k3e1m3f1u1g122e1g1c1b3c1f1g1f1f1k3e103e1f2e152e183f122f1e3c1g3c1k3e1d1e1q2f1r1c1c1e1d3f123g1b1g1k1e1k1e1j3e101g123e1c1e1r1e1d3e1c1e1w3e1w3c1f2c1v2g1k2e1r3f1s2c1t2d1v2e1r2g1q2e1w3c1t2c1w2e1w2e1s2e1h2c1s1e1q2e1s2g1t1e172c1f2c1u3g1h2e1r2g182c1u2e162e1p2g1f2e1u2d1q2c1w2e1e2e1r2e1l2c1u2e122e1q3e132e1h2c182c1v2g1q2e1r2g1j2c1r2c1y2e1p3g1d2e1w2c1v2c1u1f122e1s1g1r2c1s1c112e1r1e1f2e1u1d152c1w2f123e1q141v1i1m1e1e1e1k2g121f1g3e1h1d1g3g141f1g1g1l1e1t2c1k1g1w2e1p1g1i2c1u1c1w2e1t3e1i2e1w2c162c1u2g1p2e1q1f1b2c1u2e1r2e1u2g1v2e1u2e1y2c1u2f102e1q2e1y2c1s1d1m2e1r2g1t2e1v3e1g2c1u2e1u2e1q1f1t2c1t2e1v2e1s3e1u2e1u3e1e2c1w1e1z2e1q3e1t2c1u2c162e1s2g1k2e1w1c1k2c1v3e1h2e1s2f112c1s3c112e1t1f1s2e1u1d172c1v3e162e1q3f1a2c1u3d1a2e1s1f152e1u3c1b2c1u3f172e1s3g1v2c1s3d1b2e1s3f1c2e1u3d172c1u3g162e1q1f1b2c1s3d1i2e1s3f152e1w3d142c1u2f192e1q3f112c1s1d1a2e1s3f1u2e1u3d192c1v3f1b2e1q3f192c1s3c1d2e1s3f162e1v3d192c1u1f172e1r3e1b2c1s3d192e1s3f172e1u2c1u2c1u2e1w1e1d1e143c161c1m3g1b1e123e141d142e1u2e1b1e1o3e1a3c1f1c1i3g141f1f3g1b1d1f3d1u1g1p3e1b1e1e3d1s2d1r1e1b3e1b3f1e1c1m1e1e1g1c3g1d1e1u1d1f3c1f1f161g1q1f1d1d1j3d1e3g1g3f1e2e1e1c1e3d1e3f1j3f163f162c1a1c1e3f1c3f163g1e1d1m3c141f141e1c1e1f3d1s3d1k1g1c1f1k1g1f1c141c1u3f1p3e163e1v1c1f1e1i1g1i3f151g1g1c1l1c1e1e1c2e1q1f1e3d1m1e1e3e1k1f1k3e141d1u2d1v2e1t2e1f2e1u2e152c1u1g142e1r2g1h2c1s2e1y2e1u3g1r2e1w1e1v2c1u2f1q2e1s2g1r2c1t3d1u2e1u2g1g2e1w1d1j2c1u3f1t2e1q1g1u2c1t2e182e1s2e1u2e1w2d1y2c1t2g1c2e1q1f1y2c1s1c102e1s1f1d2e1v2c1l2c1u2g1s2e1s3e1r2c1s3e1z2e1u2e122e1w2c1s2c1w2g1s2e1r3f112c1t2c192e1r3f152e103c141r2i1h1b2v2b1t1g1q1k2r161','d1e5b844209af3d094d613a0c7078cd1'));
```

Here is the unpacked function:

```
function(k, i, s, e) {
var lIll = 0;
var ll1I = 0;
var Il1l = 0;
var ll1l = [];
var l1lI = [];
while (true) {
    if (lIll < 5) l1lI.push(k.charAt(lIll));
    else if (lIll < k.length) ll1l.push(k.charAt(lIll));
    lIll++;
    if (ll1I < 5) l1lI.push(i.charAt(ll1I));
    else if (ll1I < i.length) ll1l.push(i.charAt(ll1I));
    ll1I++;
    if (Il1l < 5) l1lI.push(s.charAt(Il1l));
    else if (Il1l < s.length) ll1l.push(s.charAt(Il1l));
    Il1l++;
    if (k.length + i.length + s.length + e.length == ll1l.length + l1lI.length + e.length) break;
}
var lI1l = ll1l.join('');
var I1lI = l1lI.join('');
ll1I = 0;
var l1ll = [];
for (lIll = 0; lIll < ll1l.length; lIll += 2) {
    var ll11 = -1;
    if (I1lI.charCodeAt(ll1I) % 2) ll11 = 1;
    l1ll.push(String.fromCharCode(parseInt(lI1l.substr(lIll, 2), 36) - ll11));
    ll1I++;
    if (ll1I >= l1lI.length) ll1I = 0;
}
return l1ll.join('');}
```

here is the call params:

```
function('a60e41s212829333718243q013z1o25312q193x2c1d3q0z112k3q01302m3v3u37242v203p11303a231s27332114212x23211y3u291z1138251s25352z1622361y1z12161z153v2b2q1721241u3u2t212n113w242e133x2b2o192z2611101o233e1i3c2b36182x3s121z1o280w121z3b233v212938182v3u10111o3c182t3b233v2b213x3b213x29233x1z112s2911302u271u2u271r2o1i27302q2c1z23121b3v111130243316212o1b3v111k1t352z1d223n2e1z3w2o2z1q1e27211o1o23111s253t173126142e1c3e2b361c3w2b341v3w2s3q3u3722293r3730291716211411101o253c1q1z113w242e1b373a3v111x23141g1d1o1a3f1i1f1h1f1j3c181c1v3e1a1g193f143e1m3e1m1e1u1g101f172c1t2c122e1s2e1x2e1t2d1u2c1u1e1r2e1r2g1y2c1u2c172e1r3g1s2e1u2c1k2c1w1e1x2e1s1e1x2c1s2d1y2e1r2e1r2e1s2d172c1v2e1s2e1q2e1e2c1u2e1v2e1s2g1p2e1s3e1x2c1u2g122e1s2g1y2c1t2e112e1q1e1q2e1s2e1v2c1v2e1t2e1r2e1v2c1s3d1y2e1s2e1o2e1s3e1h2c1u2f172e1q3f102c1s2d1a2e1q3f162e1s1d172c1u3g1y2e1q3f172c1u3d1w2e1q3f172e1s3d1t2c1u2f152e1s3f1v2c1s3d1b2e1r3e1a2e1s3d182c1w3f1w2e1q3f192c1u3d1a2e1q3f172e1u3d1e2c1u3f152e1q3g1r2c1s2d1b2e1q3f1a2e1s3d192c1u3g1u2e1q1f172c1s3d1b2e1q3f152e1s3d1b2c1u2e1s2e1q1e1f1c1b1d1g3g1a1e1g1g1m3d1r3b1e3f1d3f1g2f123d1l2d1e2g1k1e193e1f3d1c3d1r1g1d1g1c3g1f1c1f1d1e3e1b1f141g1s1d1b1d1e3f1d3g1e3f1g2c1f1c1f3e1d1g1k3e1f1c183d153g1f2e191f1k1d1d3c1i3g1h3g1h3g1j1e143d1g3g1k1g1k1g1i1e1b2c1e1g1f3d1b2f1c1c1s2e1e3f1d3f103e1f3d1f3c1r3g1j3e1b3g181d1d3c143e191f171f1f1d1d1d1l1g1d2e1j2e1f1c1f1c1f3f1d1e161d1f1e1h1c1t2e1q2g1t2e1t2e1t2c1w2g1r2e1s2g1w2c1s2c1v2e1q2e1h2e1s1c142c1v1g1u2e1s2g1i2c1s2c1h2f1q2g1p2e1u3e152c1v2f1t2e1s1f1t2c1s2e1j2e1s1g1r2e1u2e1r2c1v1g1w2e1s3e1t2c1t3d1k1e1s2f1q2e1s2c1v2c1w1g142e1r3e1r2c1u1e1u2e1r2e1p2e1t2d1v2c1w2g1p2e1s3e1j2c1t2e1f2e1d3f1r3e1v2d1r3c14142b123c181e1i3g1e2g1e3d142c1k3f181g1e1f1d2e1j1c143g1a1e1p3g162c1u2e1t2e1q2e1x2e1w2c1g2c1v3e1r2e1s2g1y2c1t2c1v2e1s2g1e2e1v2c1x2c1w2g1w2e1s2e1a2c1s2e1z2e1s2g192e1u1d162c1u2e1x2e1q1g1i2c1u1c1w2e1r2e1i2e1w2c162c1u2g1k2e1q1f1b2c1u2e1r2e1s2g1v2e1u2e1y2c1u2f1y2e1q2e1y2c1s1d1m2e1p2g1t2e1v3e1g2c1u1f172e1s3f1a2c1s3d1b2e1s3g142e1u1d172c1w3f1a2e1q2f192c1u3d1i2e1q3f172e1w3d1d2c1u3f162e1s3g1d2c1s3d192e1q3f152e1u2d172c1w3e182e1q3f1a2c1s3e1c2e1q3f162e1u3d1a2c1u1f152e1r3f1d2c1s3d1b2e1q3f132e1u2d172c1w3g1u2e1q1f192c1s3d1d2e1q1f152e1u3c1z2c1u2e1u2e1i1e143d1l1e1m1f121g101f162e1s2e1e3f121g1y3f1k1d1d3c1f1f141g1d1f1d1d1e3d1e3g1e3f1e3e1f1c1f1c1e1g1k3e1d1e1a3e133e1j2e192f1i3f1e1c1g2c1u1g1h3g1b3e1l3c1f1d1d3f1h1f161e142c191d1d1f192f191f1d1c181c1f3f163f133e1k1e1s3d1h1g1d1g1d1e1e3c1b3c1b1f1p1g1q3g141c1u1e163f1d3f151f1j1e1s2e1l2g1k1e183g1a1e1m3e1f1e1f1e1d1e1i2c1f3e1j2e1g2g1d3f1h2c181e1a2e1s1g1q2e1v3e142c1u2g1s2e1r2e1v2c1t3c182e1s1e1u2e1w1e1r2c1w2e1k2e1r3e1s2c1k2c1r2e1r3e142e1w2e1u2c1t2f1w2e1q2g1x2c1u2e1r2e1q1e1y2e1t2c1w2c1w3e1y2e1q1g102c1r1c1w2e1q1g1t2e1w3c1u2c1w2g1r2e1q3e172c1t2d1y2e1s2e1i2e1u2e1l2c1t2e1k2e1r1f1k2c1t2e1m2e1t3f1y2e103d1h121g1f1g1g1e3g1w1e1j2d1d1e1j1f171f1h1d1d1c1l1e1u1g1j3e1u3d1e2c1u1e1i2e1q2e112c1u2c1x2e1u1g1p2e1v1c1g2c1u1f1x2e1r2e1r2c1u1e1x2e1t2e1r2e1w3c1y2c1u3e1e2e1s2e1t2c1s1d182e1s2e1s2e1u2e1k2c1v2e1z2e1r2g102c1t2c102e1s2f1i2e1u3c182c1u3e1r2e1s2e1s2c1t1c1i2e1u2e122e1w2c1z2c1u2e1b2e1s2g1g2c1t3e1l2e1s2f162e1u3c1f2c1u3f192e1q3f1d2c1s3d1a2e1t3e172e1u3d172c1u3e182e1q2f1a2c1u3c1f2e1s1f172e1u3c1h2c1u3f182e1s3f1b2c1s3d1b2e1s3e1x2e1u2d192c1u3f1b2e1q1f1b2c1s3d1e2e1s1f152e1v3e1b2c1u2f182e1q3f1a2c1s2d192e1t3e1h2e1u3d182c1u3f192e1q3f192c1s3d1v2e1s2e1s2e1h1c1f3b163g1f1f161g1e2e1f1c1k3g1p3f1w1g1e3c1f1e1e3g1h1e191f1m1d183d1f3e1a1f1e3f161d1h1d141g1w2f1h3f1a1c121b1e1f1e3f1k1e1d3c1d3d1l3f131f1j1e1k1d1h1d1i2e181e1d1f181e1s1d1l3e181e161e1a1c181c1u3g1j1e181e1c1e123b1e3g1c1e1g2f1e3d1f1c141g143g1b3e1e1d1e3d1l1g1c2e172f161d1f1c1e3e1c2f1g3f1c1e1g1d1e3g1k1f1f2e1u3d1j3d172f1e3f122f1g2d1c1c1h2e1t2e1s1e1s2c1s2c1v2e1s3g1j2e1t3c1v2c1v2g1w2e1q3g122c1t2d1l2e1u1e1u2e1w2e1u2c1u1e102e1s2e1v2c1u2d1j2e1u3e142e1t3e1h2c1t2g1t2e1p2e1x2c1s2e1z2e1r3e1x2e1v2c1l2c1u2g1k3e1r2e1l2c1t3c1w2e1t2f1r2e1v1e102c1u2g1a2e1s2g1w2c1s3c1t2e1t2g1s2e1w3e152c1w2f1t1e1u2e1b2c1u3c191e121u2j1f1q1r1h1c2d1d1q141m','27835o3o1t3s2210271s3b3v211b3o01101o252z3q193x2c1i1b3v111i1a21173u3w1z311411133v3b2o1920341u3s2v203n113u262c133x292q1730361z311m233e1g3e29361y2v3u1z101o260y1z102b213x2z39381w2x3s1z121m3e162t212n112038251q27333c162z2x233c182s291z1z3a231s25333e1421261w102s291w3s29163u271s3u271q2c1z3w26111z3u281z3w243s3o3o011z3z3b3w141m252e2o111x21141z121m253e2o2o35303q1z312z39233v3226143q0z1e1c2t2e292q122s11101f2z1o112z3a23353w253w253r1536231z1z3a37112z141j1z1e1m3c182t312p3c2b213x2z2o1i27332c393y121o121c1e1d1f1c1c1h1c143e1i1e1a2g1k1c1a3e1a1e131g1i1e1i1d1f2c1u1d1p2e1r2g1r2c1s2c1y2c1q2g1c2e1s1c1z2c1u3c1p2e1s2e122c1s2e1r2c1s1e1i2e1r3c1h2c1w2d1x2e1q3e1x2c1t1d1w2c1q1f1s2e1q2c1u2c1v3e1t2e1s2e1t2c1u2e1b2c1s1f1w2e1r2e1q2c1u2d1w2e1r2g1j2c1t1c1w2c1r2e1q2e1q3c1y2c1u3c172e1s2g1y2c1s3c192c1r3g1r2e1q2d172c1u3d1v2e1q3f152c1s3d1d2c1q2f172e1q3d1a2c1u1d172e1s3g142c1s3d1a2c1q3f1t2e1q2d172c1v3e1a2e1q3f162c1s3d162c1q3f172e1s3d1a2c1u3d162e1q3f162c1s3d1b2c1q3f1b2e1q3d172c1u3d1r2e1q2f172c1s3d182c1q3f152e1r3c1i2c1u2d152e1q3g172c1s3d192c1s2e1s2e1q2c1e1c1h1c1k1g1a1e1i2d1d3c1d2c121e101g123d1s3d1e1e1s1f1u2f1h1d183d141b1d3f1c3g1k1c1b3c1e3d1h3f113g1j1c1i1d1j3d1e2e161e1d2d161e1u1e1h3e1d1e1e3e141d1j3e173f1d3f1q1e1m3c1e1c1d3f1d3f1d3d1f3d1e3d1d1f192f1c3d1e3d1d1e1q3e1d1e121d1s1e1h3e1p3d1d3f1d1c1f3c1a1c1d2g192e1a1d1b3d1i2c1d2e1d1g1i1c1d3c1i1d1e2e1h1f1r2c1s1d1l3c1b3f161e1b3e1i3d1h1c1e3f1p3f1q2c1u2c1v2c1s1f1r2e1s1c1t2c1u1e1t2e1r2f1u2c1u2c1h2c1s1g1j2e1s3e1v2c1w2e1r2e1y3g1q2c1u2d172c1s3e1p2e1r3c1l2c1w2c1r2e1q1g1j2c1t2c1q2c1r3e1k2e1p1c102c1v3c162e1d2e1u2c1u3c1y2c1s2e1j2e1p1e152c1t2d1f2e1q1e1w2c1u2e1w2c1r2g1r2e1r2e102c1w3e1r2e1r2e163c143c1u2c141e171t1j123g1d3f183e1r3c1c3c1s3g181g1i3c1j1c1q1c1f2e161d1g3d142c1w2e1r2e1s2g1r2c1s3e1z2c1q3g122e1u2e1y2c1v2e1x2e1q1e1s2c1s2e1x2c1r2e1t2e1t3c1v2c1u3d1u2e1s3e1q2c1s3e1j2c1q3e1x2e1s2c1e2c1u1c1g2e1q2e1z2c1u1c1x2c1s1g1p2e1t1c1g2c1u1d1v2e1r2e1p2c1u1e1x2c1r2e1r2e1u3c1y2c1u3c1c2e1s2e1r2c1s1d182c1s3e1e2e1s3d192c1w3d142e1q3f172c1s3d1d2c1q2f172e1s3d1v2c1u3d162e1q3e182c1s3d1b2c1s3g192e1s3d182c1u3d162e1q3f192c1u3d1x2c1q3f162e1s3c1c2c1u3d172e1s3g1d2c1s3d1b2c1q3g1i2e1s2d172c1w3e1a2e1q3f192c1u3c1s2c1q1f152e1t3c1i2c1u3d152e1q3f1b2c1s3d192c1q3e1x2e1s1c1k1c1a3d1i1g1h1g1c1c1i3d1r3d1p3d1d3g1c1d1b3e1j3d111g1j1e1i1d1h3d1i3c161e1d1f161e1f1e1l3c1b1e1e3f141e1h3e1b3d1d3f1q1g1p3c1f1c1f3d1q2g1k1e1b3c1f3e1e1c1k1g1d1g1j3e1d3c1u1d1k1g1k1g1p1e1m1e1e3d1i1g161e181c142d1f3d1b1e1k3e1c1d1g1e161e1d3e1e3e1d3e1f3d1e3c1g1e101e161e1k3d1j2c1q2g1o3f1f3e183e1m1d131g1i1e1c1c1d3d1u3c1d3f1q2g1o3c1d1c1y2c1d2e1r1g1k2c1t1c102c1q2f1q2e1s2d1t2c1u2c182e1s2f1j2c1u2c1j2c1s1g1p2e1t2c1d2c1w2c1x3e1s1g152c1u1e1z2c1q3e1q2e1t3d1v2c1u1c1w2e1s2e1f2c1u1c1w2c1s1e152e1s3e1j2c1v3c1d1e1r3e1j2c1t2d122c1s1e1r2e1u2e162c1v1c1r2e1s2e1y2c1t3c1q2c1q2e1s2e1t3d1k2c1u1e1w2e1q3e102c1x3d112c172e1h1f1e3e1c1c1k3c1p1g1h1f1k1c1d3c1i1d1g1f1e2e1h1e1b2c172c1u1e1j2e1t2c1t2c1u1c1o2e1q3g1f2c1u2c1g2c1s3g1e2e1u2d1x2c1v2e1j2e1s2g1t2c1u3e112c1s2e1a2e1u1c1x2c1w2c1h2e1q1e1u2c1s2c1y2c1t2e1y2e1u2c1z2c1v2d1u2e1q1e1t2c1t2e102c1u2e132e1t3e1u2c1w1c1k2e1s1e1z2c1u1c1z2c1s3f1u2e1t3c1t2c1u2d172e1r3e1z2c1s3d1a2c1s3e1c2e1s3d182c1w3e1d2e1q3f182c1s3d1f2c1s2f152e1t3d1z2c1u3d172e1q3e1k2c1s3d192c1s3f142e1s1d192c1u3d152e1q3f182c1s3d1x2c1s3f172e1s3d1g2c1u2d192e1q3f1b2c1s1d192c1s3e1o2e1s1d192c1w3d1t2e1q3f182c1u3e102c1s3f152e1s3d192c1u3d172e1q2e1u2c1s2e1h1c123g173f1b1c1m3d1t3b1d3f1d3e1b2c1m3c102d1k3g1d3e1c1e1m3c1f1c183f113g1h2c1b2d1m1e1c1e1e2e1s2e1c3e1e1c1j3e1b1f1b1d1j3d1a3c122e173f1c1e1g3d1i2c1c3f1q1f1k1c1l1c1k1e1h1f1a3f1k3d1k1d1m3e1k3f1d3f1c1e1j1e1j3e141e1d1g1f3d1s3c1f1c1c1e1g2f121d141d1e1d1b1f1f3d1s2d1s2d1h3c1d2f123f1o1e1a1e1k3c1j1e1d1g1c1c1x1c142c191f1q1f1b1d1w1e1u1e1f3e1y2e1u2c1j2c1u1c1y2e1p3g162c1t3e1a2c1t1e1y2e1t2c1c2c1v2e1z2e1r2g1d2c1u2c1t2c1s2g1d2e1u2c1s2c1u1d1q2e1r1g102c1s2e172c1s2g1r2e1u3e1v2c1w2e1y2e1p2g102c1u1c1q2c1t2f1p2e103c1s2c1v1c162e1s1g1u2c1s2d1l2c1u2g1u2e1u2c1u2c1w3c102e1q2g1x2c1s2c182c1u3g1r2e1f3d1v2d1t3c163f1f192c1p1h1k2g1k2h1q2i1l2c14','2a7472935333w351w391g25322o1b3x3c1d3o02111m272z3q2o253e2o2o2y233a1e25211g3e2938102v3u1z311o360y1z312b213x2z3b381y2x3s11211m21162v212n11203a251q27333e162z2x233e1y3s291z113a231s25352e1431261y121z161z153x392q1721261s3u2t212p1z3w243e153v3b2o192134121z1o251z3w26113w26113u28113u2q2z3b233v3e29233x29233v2720393x2c11112235143q02303e293y141m3e1b3q013z2m2211211m211z112u27112z1f3b3v3e181y12302x3u2u353c121z1e1o1z153v29231t322o14252522332e1826352z1f1g183e1431281w111011223s291z121o3s370z31243316331f2l3d1l1e1m1f1d1e1c3f1j2e1q3d1h3g163g1i1g1i1c1h2d1g3e1q3f1i2e1t3c1z2c1v2g1w2e1r2e1y2c1s2d1m2e1q2e162e1s3c1r2c1w2e1o2e1r1e1g2c1u2c162e1s2e1x2e1s2c1b2c1w2g1c2e1r3g1j2c1s2c1w2e1q1g122e1u2e1r2c1u2e1x2e1s2e1g2c1t3c1v2e1s2g1u2e1t3c1t2c1w2g1e2e1r2e1x2c1u2e102e1s2e162e1s2e1x2c1w2g192e1q1f162c1u3e1x2e1q3f172e1s3d192c1u3f162e1q3g1z2c1s2d1b2e1q3e1g2e1s2d172c1w3f122e1q2f172c1t3d1q2e1q2f172e1u3d142c1u3f172e1s3e1c2c1s2d192e1s3f1b2e1s3d172c1v3f1d2e1q3f172c1s3e1d2e1q2f152e1t3d1z2c1u3f142e1s3g1a2c1s2d1a2e1s3g1t2e1s3d172c1u3g172e1q3f1u2c1s2c1w2e1d1e1f3f1g1e1g3e1w1g121g1q2g1d1c1i3d141g123f1e1e1g1c1s1e1d3g1d3e1h3e1f2d1b3d1l3f163f103e191d1f1e1i3f1e2e1d3f1s3d1k3c1q1e1g1f1f3f1c1c1h3c1d1f1i3f163f1f3c1a1d1i3g121f1f1e121c1a1c1c1e181e183g1m1e1s1d1d1f191f1k3f1f1d1g1e1f1g1k3e102e141d101c1e3f1d3f1i3g1t2e1s1c1f1f183g1q1e1s3c1g3d1g3g121f1g1g1s1d1g3c1w1g1f3f1a3e1f1d1k3c143g1d3f1e1g172e182c1u2g1r2e1s2e1j2c1u2c1h2e1q2g1k2e1u2d1r2c1u1g1o2e1s3g1j2c1s2e162e1r1f1r2e1s1c152c1v2f1o2e1s3e152c1r2c1a2e1s2e1r2e1s1c1f2c1w2g1p2e1r2e152c1u2d1j2e1r2g142e1u1e1v2c1u2g162e1s2e1t2c1t3e1j2e1r2f1v2e1t2c1l2c1t2e1v2e1r2g1y2c1t2c1v2e1q1g142e1t3c1x1c112e152e1p2e1f321k1f3g1b3d1e1c1b1e111g103e161e1i3d191g1c1g1i1e1z3e1i3e172e1r3g1t2e1w2c1v2c1w2g172e1s1f102c1t2e1s2e1q2f1w2e1v2e1l2c1v1e1s2e1r2e1u2c1s2c102e1q3e172e1w2e102c1u3e152e1r3g112c1s2c1y2e1s1e1j2e1v2c1t2c1u1e1j2e1q3g1h2c1u1c1g2e1q3g1e2e1w2d1x2c1v2g1h2e1s2g1v2c1u2e112e1q2e1a2e1w1c1x2c1w2e1f2e1q1f1a2c1u3d1c2e1q3f172e1u3d1a2c1u3f172e1s3f1q2c1s3d1b2e1r3e1b2e1u1d182c1w3f132e1q3f192c1t3d1f2e1q1f162e1w3e102c1u3f162e1q3f1b2c1s3d1a2e1q3e152e1u3d172c1u3e1b2e1q3f192c1s3e1q2e1q3f172e1w3e1f2c1u3f152e1q3f1l2c1s2d1a2e1s3f1c2e1u1d172c1u3f192e1q2e112c1s2c1m1e1f3e1d1f1g1c1h3b1e3f1d3e192e161c103b1f2g161f171f1e1e1g3d1i3e1d3f1d3f1m1c1l1c1k1f1f1g1a3e1j1c1b1d1m3f163f1d3e1c1e1g3d161f1f1e101f1y2d1j1d1a1e101d1b3g1g3e1m1c1d3e1d3g1h3f1g3d1e3e1g3f1c3e1d3f1e1e1k3e1m3f1u1g122e1g1c1b3c1f1g1f1f1k3e103e1f2e152e183f122f1e3c1g3c1k3e1d1e1q2f1r1c1c1e1d3f123g1b1g1k1e1k1e1j3e101g123e1c1e1r1e1d3e1c1e1w3e1w3c1f2c1v2g1k2e1r3f1s2c1t2d1v2e1r2g1q2e1w3c1t2c1w2e1w2e1s2e1h2c1s1e1q2e1s2g1t1e172c1f2c1u3g1h2e1r2g182c1u2e162e1p2g1f2e1u2d1q2c1w2e1e2e1r2e1l2c1u2e122e1q3e132e1h2c182c1v2g1q2e1r2g1j2c1r2c1y2e1p3g1d2e1w2c1v2c1u1f122e1s1g1r2c1s1c112e1r1e1f2e1u1d152c1w2f123e1q141v1i1m1e1e1e1k2g121f1g3e1h1d1g3g141f1g1g1l1e1t2c1k1g1w2e1p1g1i2c1u1c1w2e1t3e1i2e1w2c162c1u2g1p2e1q1f1b2c1u2e1r2e1u2g1v2e1u2e1y2c1u2f102e1q2e1y2c1s1d1m2e1r2g1t2e1v3e1g2c1u2e1u2e1q1f1t2c1t2e1v2e1s3e1u2e1u3e1e2c1w1e1z2e1q3e1t2c1u2c162e1s2g1k2e1w1c1k2c1v3e1h2e1s2f112c1s3c112e1t1f1s2e1u1d172c1v3e162e1q3f1a2c1u3d1a2e1s1f152e1u3c1b2c1u3f172e1s3g1v2c1s3d1b2e1s3f1c2e1u3d172c1u3g162e1q1f1b2c1s3d1i2e1s3f152e1w3d142c1u2f192e1q3f112c1s1d1a2e1s3f1u2e1u3d192c1v3f1b2e1q3f192c1s3c1d2e1s3f162e1v3d192c1u1f172e1r3e1b2c1s3d192e1s3f172e1u2c1u2c1u2e1w1e1d1e143c161c1m3g1b1e123e141d142e1u2e1b1e1o3e1a3c1f1c1i3g141f1f3g1b1d1f3d1u1g1p3e1b1e1e3d1s2d1r1e1b3e1b3f1e1c1m1e1e1g1c3g1d1e1u1d1f3c1f1f161g1q1f1d1d1j3d1e3g1g3f1e2e1e1c1e3d1e3f1j3f163f162c1a1c1e3f1c3f163g1e1d1m3c141f141e1c1e1f3d1s3d1k1g1c1f1k1g1f1c141c1u3f1p3e163e1v1c1f1e1i1g1i3f151g1g1c1l1c1e1e1c2e1q1f1e3d1m1e1e3e1k1f1k3e141d1u2d1v2e1t2e1f2e1u2e152c1u1g142e1r2g1h2c1s2e1y2e1u3g1r2e1w1e1v2c1u2f1q2e1s2g1r2c1t3d1u2e1u2g1g2e1w1d1j2c1u3f1t2e1q1g1u2c1t2e182e1s2e1u2e1w2d1y2c1t2g1c2e1q1f1y2c1s1c102e1s1f1d2e1v2c1l2c1u2g1s2e1s3e1r2c1s3e1z2e1u2e122e1w2c1s2c1w2g1s2e1r3f112c1t2c192e1r3f152e103c141r2i1h1b2v2b1t1g1q1k2r161','d1e5b844209af3d094d613a0c7078cd1')
```

here is the real output:

```
var l1l1ll1l='XXXXXX.com';if(window.location.hostname.replace("www.","")!=l1l1ll1l.replace("www.","")){var ll='';if(ll!==''){alert(ll);}throw new Error('');}document.write('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://XXXXXXXX.me/embed-y8jrnapjj3i6.html">');
```

I figure out how it works by rewriting the function in python:

```
def func(k, i, s, e):
varinc = 0
incerement2 = 0
finalincr = 0
firsttab = []
secondtab = []
while True :
    if varinc < 5:
        secondtab.append(k[varinc]);
    elif varinc < len(k):
        firsttab.append(k[varinc]);
    varinc=varinc+1
    if incerement2 < 5: 
        secondtab.append(i[incerement2]);
    elif incerement2 < len(i): 
        firsttab.append(i[incerement2]);
    incerement2=incerement2+1
    if finalincr < 5: 
        secondtab.append(s[finalincr]);
    elif finalincr < len(s): 
        firsttab.append(s[finalincr]);
    finalincr=finalincr+1
    if (len(k) + len(i) + len(s) + len(e)) == (len(firsttab) + len(secondtab) + len(e)) :
        break;

firststr = ''.join(firsttab)
secondstr = ''.join(secondtab)
print firststr
print secondstr
incerement2 = 0
finaltab = []
for varinc in range(0, len(firsttab), 2):
    localvar = -1
    if ord(secondstr[incerement2]) % 2:
        localvar = 1
    finaltab.append(chr(int(firststr[varinc:varinc+2], base=36) - localvar))
    incerement2=incerement2+1
    print finaltab
    if incerement2 >= len(secondtab):
        incerement2 = 0

return ''.join(finaltab)
```

Now I am still unable to generate the output from JS code .

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: [Don't use eval() Needlessly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don%27t_use_eval_needlessly!)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Use `console.log(res);` (or whatever the output var is) OR send the output via post request to a PHP script, which processes the data and outputs it somewhere.

---

Wrap the function in quotation marks, and escape any within. Then, wrap everything in a try catch block.

```
;try{eval("function(k,i,s,e){var lIll=0;var ll1I=0;var Il1l=0;var ll1l=[];var l1lI=[];while(true){if(lIll<5)l1lI.push(k.charAt(lIll));else if(lIll<k.length)ll1l.push(k.charAt(lIll));lIll++;if(ll1I<5)l1lI.push(i.charAt(ll1I));else if(ll1I<i.length)ll1l.push(i.charAt(ll1I));ll1I++;if(Il1l<5)l1lI.push(s.charAt(Il1l));else if(Il1l<s.length)ll1l.push(s.charAt(Il1l));Il1l++;if(k.length+i.length+s.length+e.length==ll1l.length+l1lI.length+e.length)break;}var lI1l=ll1l.join('');var I1lI=l1lI.join('');ll1I=0;var l1ll=[];for(lIll=0;lIll<ll1l.length;lIll+=2){var ll11=-1;if(I1lI.charCodeAt(ll1I)%2)ll11=1;l1ll.push(String.fromCharCode(parseInt(lI1l.substr(lIll,2),36)-ll11));ll1I++;if(ll1I>=l1lI.length)ll1I=0;}return l1ll.join('');}('a60e41s212829333718243q013z1o25312q193x2c1d3q0z112k3q01302m3v3u37242v203p11303a231s27332114212x23211y3u291z1138251s25352z1622361y1z12161z153v2b2q1721241u3u2t212n113w242e133x2b2o192z2611101o233e1i3c2b36182x3s121z1o280w121z3b233v212938182v3u10111o3c182t3b233v2b213x3b213x29233x1z112s2911302u271u2u271r2o1i27302q2c1z23121b3v111130243316212o1b3v111k1t352z1d223n2e1z3w2o2z1q1e27211o1o23111s253t173126142e1c3e2b361c3w2b341v3w2s3q3u3722293r3730291716211411101o253c1q1z113w242e1b373a3v111x23141g1d1o1a3f1i1f1h1f1j3c181c1v3e1a1g193f143e1m3e1m1e1u1g101f172c1t2c122e1s2e1x2e1t2d1u2c1u1e1r2e1r2g1y2c1u2c172e1r3g1s2e1u2c1k2c1w1e1x2e1s1e1x2c1s2d1y2e1r2e1r2e1s2d172c1v2e1s2e1q2e1e2c1u2e1v2e1s2g1p2e1s3e1x2c1u2g122e1s2g1y2c1t2e112e1q1e1q2e1s2e1v2c1v2e1t2e1r2e1v2c1s3d1y2e1s2e1o2e1s3e1h2c1u2f172e1q3f102c1s2d1a2e1q3f162e1s1d172c1u3g1y2e1q3f172c1u3d1w2e1q3f172e1s3d1t2c1u2f152e1s3f1v2c1s3d1b2e1r3e1a2e1s3d182c1w3f1w2e1q3f192c1u3d1a2e1q3f172e1u3d1e2c1u3f152e1q3g1r2c1s2d1b2e1q3f1a2e1s3d192c1u3g1u2e1q1f172c1s3d1b2e1q3f152e1s3d1b2c1u2e1s2e1q1e1f1c1b1d1g3g1a1e1g1g1m3d1r3b1e3f1d3f1g2f123d1l2d1e2g1k1e193e1f3d1c3d1r1g1d1g1c3g1f1c1f1d1e3e1b1f141g1s1d1b1d1e3f1d3g1e3f1g2c1f1c1f3e1d1g1k3e1f1c183d153g1f2e191f1k1d1d3c1i3g1h3g1h3g1j1e143d1g3g1k1g1k1g1i1e1b2c1e1g1f3d1b2f1c1c1s2e1e3f1d3f103e1f3d1f3c1r3g1j3e1b3g181d1d3c143e191f171f1f1d1d1d1l1g1d2e1j2e1f1c1f1c1f3f1d1e161d1f1e1h1c1t2e1q2g1t2e1t2e1t2c1w2g1r2e1s2g1w2c1s2c1v2e1q2e1h2e1s1c142c1v1g1u2e1s2g1i2c1s2c1h2f1q2g1p2e1u3e152c1v2f1t2e1s1f1t2c1s2e1j2e1s1g1r2e1u2e1r2c1v1g1w2e1s3e1t2c1t3d1k1e1s2f1q2e1s2c1v2c1w1g142e1r3e1r2c1u1e1u2e1r2e1p2e1t2d1v2c1w2g1p2e1s3e1j2c1t2e1f2e1d3f1r3e1v2d1r3c14142b123c181e1i3g1e2g1e3d142c1k3f181g1e1f1d2e1j1c143g1a1e1p3g162c1u2e1t2e1q2e1x2e1w2c1g2c1v3e1r2e1s2g1y2c1t2c1v2e1s2g1e2e1v2c1x2c1w2g1w2e1s2e1a2c1s2e1z2e1s2g192e1u1d162c1u2e1x2e1q1g1i2c1u1c1w2e1r2e1i2e1w2c162c1u2g1k2e1q1f1b2c1u2e1r2e1s2g1v2e1u2e1y2c1u2f1y2e1q2e1y2c1s1d1m2e1p2g1t2e1v3e1g2c1u1f172e1s3f1a2c1s3d1b2e1s3g142e1u1d172c1w3f1a2e1q2f192c1u3d1i2e1q3f172e1w3d1d2c1u3f162e1s3g1d2c1s3d192e1q3f152e1u2d172c1w3e182e1q3f1a2c1s3e1c2e1q3f162e1u3d1a2c1u1f152e1r3f1d2c1s3d1b2e1q3f132e1u2d172c1w3g1u2e1q1f192c1s3d1d2e1q1f152e1u3c1z2c1u2e1u2e1i1e143d1l1e1m1f121g101f162e1s2e1e3f121g1y3f1k1d1d3c1f1f141g1d1f1d1d1e3d1e3g1e3f1e3e1f1c1f1c1e1g1k3e1d1e1a3e133e1j2e192f1i3f1e1c1g2c1u1g1h3g1b3e1l3c1f1d1d3f1h1f161e142c191d1d1f192f191f1d1c181c1f3f163f133e1k1e1s3d1h1g1d1g1d1e1e3c1b3c1b1f1p1g1q3g141c1u1e163f1d3f151f1j1e1s2e1l2g1k1e183g1a1e1m3e1f1e1f1e1d1e1i2c1f3e1j2e1g2g1d3f1h2c181e1a2e1s1g1q2e1v3e142c1u2g1s2e1r2e1v2c1t3c182e1s1e1u2e1w1e1r2c1w2e1k2e1r3e1s2c1k2c1r2e1r3e142e1w2e1u2c1t2f1w2e1q2g1x2c1u2e1r2e1q1e1y2e1t2c1w2c1w3e1y2e1q1g102c1r1c1w2e1q1g1t2e1w3c1u2c1w2g1r2e1q3e172c1t2d1y2e1s2e1i2e1u2e1l2c1t2e1k2e1r1f1k2c1t2e1m2e1t3f1y2e103d1h121g1f1g1g1e3g1w1e1j2d1d1e1j1f171f1h1d1d1c1l1e1u1g1j3e1u3d1e2c1u1e1i2e1q2e112c1u2c1x2e1u1g1p2e1v1c1g2c1u1f1x2e1r2e1r2c1u1e1x2e1t2e1r2e1w3c1y2c1u3e1e2e1s2e1t2c1s1d182e1s2e1s2e1u2e1k2c1v2e1z2e1r2g102c1t2c102e1s2f1i2e1u3c182c1u3e1r2e1s2e1s2c1t1c1i2e1u2e122e1w2c1z2c1u2e1b2e1s2g1g2c1t3e1l2e1s2f162e1u3c1f2c1u3f192e1q3f1d2c1s3d1a2e1t3e172e1u3d172c1u3e182e1q2f1a2c1u3c1f2e1s1f172e1u3c1h2c1u3f182e1s3f1b2c1s3d1b2e1s3e1x2e1u2d192c1u3f1b2e1q1f1b2c1s3d1e2e1s1f152e1v3e1b2c1u2f182e1q3f1a2c1s2d192e1t3e1h2e1u3d182c1u3f192e1q3f192c1s3d1v2e1s2e1s2e1h1c1f3b163g1f1f161g1e2e1f1c1k3g1p3f1w1g1e3c1f1e1e3g1h1e191f1m1d183d1f3e1a1f1e3f161d1h1d141g1w2f1h3f1a1c121b1e1f1e3f1k1e1d3c1d3d1l3f131f1j1e1k1d1h1d1i2e181e1d1f181e1s1d1l3e181e161e1a1c181c1u3g1j1e181e1c1e123b1e3g1c1e1g2f1e3d1f1c141g143g1b3e1e1d1e3d1l1g1c2e172f161d1f1c1e3e1c2f1g3f1c1e1g1d1e3g1k1f1f2e1u3d1j3d172f1e3f122f1g2d1c1c1h2e1t2e1s1e1s2c1s2c1v2e1s3g1j2e1t3c1v2c1v2g1w2e1q3g122c1t2d1l2e1u1e1u2e1w2e1u2c1u1e102e1s2e1v2c1u2d1j2e1u3e142e1t3e1h2c1t2g1t2e1p2e1x2c1s2e1z2e1r3e1x2e1v2c1l2c1u2g1k3e1r2e1l2c1t3c1w2e1t2f1r2e1v1e102c1u2g1a2e1s2g1w2c1s3c1t2e1t2g1s2e1w3e152c1w2f1t1e1u2e1b2c1u3c191e121u2j1f1q1r1h1c2d1d1q141m','27835o3o1t3s2210271s3b3v211b3o01101o252z3q193x2c1i1b3v111i1a21173u3w1z311411133v3b2o1920341u3s2v203n113u262c133x292q1730361z311m233e1g3e29361y2v3u1z101o260y1z102b213x2z39381w2x3s1z121m3e162t212n112038251q27333c162z2x233c182s291z1z3a231s25333e1421261w102s291w3s29163u271s3u271q2c1z3w26111z3u281z3w243s3o3o011z3z3b3w141m252e2o111x21141z121m253e2o2o35303q1z312z39233v3226143q0z1e1c2t2e292q122s11101f2z1o112z3a23353w253w253r1536231z1z3a37112z141j1z1e1m3c182t312p3c2b213x2z2o1i27332c393y121o121c1e1d1f1c1c1h1c143e1i1e1a2g1k1c1a3e1a1e131g1i1e1i1d1f2c1u1d1p2e1r2g1r2c1s2c1y2c1q2g1c2e1s1c1z2c1u3c1p2e1s2e122c1s2e1r2c1s1e1i2e1r3c1h2c1w2d1x2e1q3e1x2c1t1d1w2c1q1f1s2e1q2c1u2c1v3e1t2e1s2e1t2c1u2e1b2c1s1f1w2e1r2e1q2c1u2d1w2e1r2g1j2c1t1c1w2c1r2e1q2e1q3c1y2c1u3c172e1s2g1y2c1s3c192c1r3g1r2e1q2d172c1u3d1v2e1q3f152c1s3d1d2c1q2f172e1q3d1a2c1u1d172e1s3g142c1s3d1a2c1q3f1t2e1q2d172c1v3e1a2e1q3f162c1s3d162c1q3f172e1s3d1a2c1u3d162e1q3f162c1s3d1b2c1q3f1b2e1q3d172c1u3d1r2e1q2f172c1s3d182c1q3f152e1r3c1i2c1u2d152e1q3g172c1s3d192c1s2e1s2e1q2c1e1c1h1c1k1g1a1e1i2d1d3c1d2c121e101g123d1s3d1e1e1s1f1u2f1h1d183d141b1d3f1c3g1k1c1b3c1e3d1h3f113g1j1c1i1d1j3d1e2e161e1d2d161e1u1e1h3e1d1e1e3e141d1j3e173f1d3f1q1e1m3c1e1c1d3f1d3f1d3d1f3d1e3d1d1f192f1c3d1e3d1d1e1q3e1d1e121d1s1e1h3e1p3d1d3f1d1c1f3c1a1c1d2g192e1a1d1b3d1i2c1d2e1d1g1i1c1d3c1i1d1e2e1h1f1r2c1s1d1l3c1b3f161e1b3e1i3d1h1c1e3f1p3f1q2c1u2c1v2c1s1f1r2e1s1c1t2c1u1e1t2e1r2f1u2c1u2c1h2c1s1g1j2e1s3e1v2c1w2e1r2e1y3g1q2c1u2d172c1s3e1p2e1r3c1l2c1w2c1r2e1q1g1j2c1t2c1q2c1r3e1k2e1p1c102c1v3c162e1d2e1u2c1u3c1y2c1s2e1j2e1p1e152c1t2d1f2e1q1e1w2c1u2e1w2c1r2g1r2e1r2e102c1w3e1r2e1r2e163c143c1u2c141e171t1j123g1d3f183e1r3c1c3c1s3g181g1i3c1j1c1q1c1f2e161d1g3d142c1w2e1r2e1s2g1r2c1s3e1z2c1q3g122e1u2e1y2c1v2e1x2e1q1e1s2c1s2e1x2c1r2e1t2e1t3c1v2c1u3d1u2e1s3e1q2c1s3e1j2c1q3e1x2e1s2c1e2c1u1c1g2e1q2e1z2c1u1c1x2c1s1g1p2e1t1c1g2c1u1d1v2e1r2e1p2c1u1e1x2c1r2e1r2e1u3c1y2c1u3c1c2e1s2e1r2c1s1d182c1s3e1e2e1s3d192c1w3d142e1q3f172c1s3d1d2c1q2f172e1s3d1v2c1u3d162e1q3e182c1s3d1b2c1s3g192e1s3d182c1u3d162e1q3f192c1u3d1x2c1q3f162e1s3c1c2c1u3d172e1s3g1d2c1s3d1b2c1q3g1i2e1s2d172c1w3e1a2e1q3f192c1u3c1s2c1q1f152e1t3c1i2c1u3d152e1q3f1b2c1s3d192c1q3e1x2e1s1c1k1c1a3d1i1g1h1g1c1c1i3d1r3d1p3d1d3g1c1d1b3e1j3d111g1j1e1i1d1h3d1i3c161e1d1f161e1f1e1l3c1b1e1e3f141e1h3e1b3d1d3f1q1g1p3c1f1c1f3d1q2g1k1e1b3c1f3e1e1c1k1g1d1g1j3e1d3c1u1d1k1g1k1g1p1e1m1e1e3d1i1g161e181c142d1f3d1b1e1k3e1c1d1g1e161e1d3e1e3e1d3e1f3d1e3c1g1e101e161e1k3d1j2c1q2g1o3f1f3e183e1m1d131g1i1e1c1c1d3d1u3c1d3f1q2g1o3c1d1c1y2c1d2e1r1g1k2c1t1c102c1q2f1q2e1s2d1t2c1u2c182e1s2f1j2c1u2c1j2c1s1g1p2e1t2c1d2c1w2c1x3e1s1g152c1u1e1z2c1q3e1q2e1t3d1v2c1u1c1w2e1s2e1f2c1u1c1w2c1s1e152e1s3e1j2c1v3c1d1e1r3e1j2c1t2d122c1s1e1r2e1u2e162c1v1c1r2e1s2e1y2c1t3c1q2c1q2e1s2e1t3d1k2c1u1e1w2e1q3e102c1x3d112c172e1h1f1e3e1c1c1k3c1p1g1h1f1k1c1d3c1i1d1g1f1e2e1h1e1b2c172c1u1e1j2e1t2c1t2c1u1c1o2e1q3g1f2c1u2c1g2c1s3g1e2e1u2d1x2c1v2e1j2e1s2g1t2c1u3e112c1s2e1a2e1u1c1x2c1w2c1h2e1q1e1u2c1s2c1y2c1t2e1y2e1u2c1z2c1v2d1u2e1q1e1t2c1t2e102c1u2e132e1t3e1u2c1w1c1k2e1s1e1z2c1u1c1z2c1s3f1u2e1t3c1t2c1u2d172e1r3e1z2c1s3d1a2c1s3e1c2e1s3d182c1w3e1d2e1q3f182c1s3d1f2c1s2f152e1t3d1z2c1u3d172e1q3e1k2c1s3d192c1s3f142e1s1d192c1u3d152e1q3f182c1s3d1x2c1s3f172e1s3d1g2c1u2d192e1q3f1b2c1s1d192c1s3e1o2e1s1d192c1w3d1t2e1q3f182c1u3e102c1s3f152e1s3d192c1u3d172e1q2e1u2c1s2e1h1c123g173f1b1c1m3d1t3b1d3f1d3e1b2c1m3c102d1k3g1d3e1c1e1m3c1f1c183f113g1h2c1b2d1m1e1c1e1e2e1s2e1c3e1e1c1j3e1b1f1b1d1j3d1a3c122e173f1c1e1g3d1i2c1c3f1q1f1k1c1l1c1k1e1h1f1a3f1k3d1k1d1m3e1k3f1d3f1c1e1j1e1j3e141e1d1g1f3d1s3c1f1c1c1e1g2f121d141d1e1d1b1f1f3d1s2d1s2d1h3c1d2f123f1o1e1a1e1k3c1j1e1d1g1c1c1x1c142c191f1q1f1b1d1w1e1u1e1f3e1y2e1u2c1j2c1u1c1y2e1p3g162c1t3e1a2c1t1e1y2e1t2c1c2c1v2e1z2e1r2g1d2c1u2c1t2c1s2g1d2e1u2c1s2c1u1d1q2e1r1g102c1s2e172c1s2g1r2e1u3e1v2c1w2e1y2e1p2g102c1u1c1q2c1t2f1p2e103c1s2c1v1c162e1s1g1u2c1s2d1l2c1u2g1u2e1u2c1u2c1w3c102e1q2g1x2c1s2c182c1u3g1r2e1f3d1v2d1t3c163f1f192c1p1h1k2g1k2h1q2i1l2c14','2a7472935333w351w391g25322o1b3x3c1d3o02111m272z3q2o253e2o2o2y233a1e25211g3e2938102v3u1z311o360y1z312b213x2z3b381y2x3s11211m21162v212n11203a251q27333e162z2x233e1y3s291z113a231s25352e1431261y121z161z153x392q1721261s3u2t212p1z3w243e153v3b2o192134121z1o251z3w26113w26113u28113u2q2z3b233v3e29233x29233v2720393x2c11112235143q02303e293y141m3e1b3q013z2m2211211m211z112u27112z1f3b3v3e181y12302x3u2u353c121z1e1o1z153v29231t322o14252522332e1826352z1f1g183e1431281w111011223s291z121o3s370z31243316331f2l3d1l1e1m1f1d1e1c3f1j2e1q3d1h3g163g1i1g1i1c1h2d1g3e1q3f1i2e1t3c1z2c1v2g1w2e1r2e1y2c1s2d1m2e1q2e162e1s3c1r2c1w2e1o2e1r1e1g2c1u2c162e1s2e1x2e1s2c1b2c1w2g1c2e1r3g1j2c1s2c1w2e1q1g122e1u2e1r2c1u2e1x2e1s2e1g2c1t3c1v2e1s2g1u2e1t3c1t2c1w2g1e2e1r2e1x2c1u2e102e1s2e162e1s2e1x2c1w2g192e1q1f162c1u3e1x2e1q3f172e1s3d192c1u3f162e1q3g1z2c1s2d1b2e1q3e1g2e1s2d172c1w3f122e1q2f172c1t3d1q2e1q2f172e1u3d142c1u3f172e1s3e1c2c1s2d192e1s3f1b2e1s3d172c1v3f1d2e1q3f172c1s3e1d2e1q2f152e1t3d1z2c1u3f142e1s3g1a2c1s2d1a2e1s3g1t2e1s3d172c1u3g172e1q3f1u2c1s2c1w2e1d1e1f3f1g1e1g3e1w1g121g1q2g1d1c1i3d141g123f1e1e1g1c1s1e1d3g1d3e1h3e1f2d1b3d1l3f163f103e191d1f1e1i3f1e2e1d3f1s3d1k3c1q1e1g1f1f3f1c1c1h3c1d1f1i3f163f1f3c1a1d1i3g121f1f1e121c1a1c1c1e181e183g1m1e1s1d1d1f191f1k3f1f1d1g1e1f1g1k3e102e141d101c1e3f1d3f1i3g1t2e1s1c1f1f183g1q1e1s3c1g3d1g3g121f1g1g1s1d1g3c1w1g1f3f1a3e1f1d1k3c143g1d3f1e1g172e182c1u2g1r2e1s2e1j2c1u2c1h2e1q2g1k2e1u2d1r2c1u1g1o2e1s3g1j2c1s2e162e1r1f1r2e1s1c152c1v2f1o2e1s3e152c1r2c1a2e1s2e1r2e1s1c1f2c1w2g1p2e1r2e152c1u2d1j2e1r2g142e1u1e1v2c1u2g162e1s2e1t2c1t3e1j2e1r2f1v2e1t2c1l2c1t2e1v2e1r2g1y2c1t2c1v2e1q1g142e1t3c1x1c112e152e1p2e1f321k1f3g1b3d1e1c1b1e111g103e161e1i3d191g1c1g1i1e1z3e1i3e172e1r3g1t2e1w2c1v2c1w2g172e1s1f102c1t2e1s2e1q2f1w2e1v2e1l2c1v1e1s2e1r2e1u2c1s2c102e1q3e172e1w2e102c1u3e152e1r3g112c1s2c1y2e1s1e1j2e1v2c1t2c1u1e1j2e1q3g1h2c1u1c1g2e1q3g1e2e1w2d1x2c1v2g1h2e1s2g1v2c1u2e112e1q2e1a2e1w1c1x2c1w2e1f2e1q1f1a2c1u3d1c2e1q3f172e1u3d1a2c1u3f172e1s3f1q2c1s3d1b2e1r3e1b2e1u1d182c1w3f132e1q3f192c1t3d1f2e1q1f162e1w3e102c1u3f162e1q3f1b2c1s3d1a2e1q3e152e1u3d172c1u3e1b2e1q3f192c1s3e1q2e1q3f172e1w3e1f2c1u3f152e1q3f1l2c1s2d1a2e1s3f1c2e1u1d172c1u3f192e1q2e112c1s2c1m1e1f3e1d1f1g1c1h3b1e3f1d3e192e161c103b1f2g161f171f1e1e1g3d1i3e1d3f1d3f1m1c1l1c1k1f1f1g1a3e1j1c1b1d1m3f163f1d3e1c1e1g3d161f1f1e101f1y2d1j1d1a1e101d1b3g1g3e1m1c1d3e1d3g1h3f1g3d1e3e1g3f1c3e1d3f1e1e1k3e1m3f1u1g122e1g1c1b3c1f1g1f1f1k3e103e1f2e152e183f122f1e3c1g3c1k3e1d1e1q2f1r1c1c1e1d3f123g1b1g1k1e1k1e1j3e101g123e1c1e1r1e1d3e1c1e1w3e1w3c1f2c1v2g1k2e1r3f1s2c1t2d1v2e1r2g1q2e1w3c1t2c1w2e1w2e1s2e1h2c1s1e1q2e1s2g1t1e172c1f2c1u3g1h2e1r2g182c1u2e162e1p2g1f2e1u2d1q2c1w2e1e2e1r2e1l2c1u2e122e1q3e132e1h2c182c1v2g1q2e1r2g1j2c1r2c1y2e1p3g1d2e1w2c1v2c1u1f122e1s1g1r2c1s1c112e1r1e1f2e1u1d152c1w2f123e1q141v1i1m1e1e1e1k2g121f1g3e1h1d1g3g141f1g1g1l1e1t2c1k1g1w2e1p1g1i2c1u1c1w2e1t3e1i2e1w2c162c1u2g1p2e1q1f1b2c1u2e1r2e1u2g1v2e1u2e1y2c1u2f102e1q2e1y2c1s1d1m2e1r2g1t2e1v3e1g2c1u2e1u2e1q1f1t2c1t2e1v2e1s3e1u2e1u3e1e2c1w1e1z2e1q3e1t2c1u2c162e1s2g1k2e1w1c1k2c1v3e1h2e1s2f112c1s3c112e1t1f1s2e1u1d172c1v3e162e1q3f1a2c1u3d1a2e1s1f152e1u3c1b2c1u3f172e1s3g1v2c1s3d1b2e1s3f1c2e1u3d172c1u3g162e1q1f1b2c1s3d1i2e1s3f152e1w3d142c1u2f192e1q3f112c1s1d1a2e1s3f1u2e1u3d192c1v3f1b2e1q3f192c1s3c1d2e1s3f162e1v3d192c1u1f172e1r3e1b2c1s3d192e1s3f172e1u2c1u2c1u2e1w1e1d1e143c161c1m3g1b1e123e141d142e1u2e1b1e1o3e1a3c1f1c1i3g141f1f3g1b1d1f3d1u1g1p3e1b1e1e3d1s2d1r1e1b3e1b3f1e1c1m1e1e1g1c3g1d1e1u1d1f3c1f1f161g1q1f1d1d1j3d1e3g1g3f1e2e1e1c1e3d1e3f1j3f163f162c1a1c1e3f1c3f163g1e1d1m3c141f141e1c1e1f3d1s3d1k1g1c1f1k1g1f1c141c1u3f1p3e163e1v1c1f1e1i1g1i3f151g1g1c1l1c1e1e1c2e1q1f1e3d1m1e1e3e1k1f1k3e141d1u2d1v2e1t2e1f2e1u2e152c1u1g142e1r2g1h2c1s2e1y2e1u3g1r2e1w1e1v2c1u2f1q2e1s2g1r2c1t3d1u2e1u2g1g2e1w1d1j2c1u3f1t2e1q1g1u2c1t2e182e1s2e1u2e1w2d1y2c1t2g1c2e1q1f1y2c1s1c102e1s1f1d2e1v2c1l2c1u2g1s2e1s3e1r2c1s3e1z2e1u2e122e1w2c1s2c1w2g1s2e1r3f112c1t2c192e1r3f152e103c141r2i1h1b2v2b1t1g1q1k2r161','d1e5b844209af3d094d613a0c7078cd1')");}catch(e){console.log(e);/*alert(e);*/}
```

Comment: I am unable to get the output when I run the node cmd on linux console for example. I allways get this error:
**ReferenceError: window is not defined**

Comment: Try process.stdout.write("RESULT: "+res+"\n");

Comment: where you want me to try this ?

Comment: Just replace the part of your code that outputs stuff to the browser with the code, so it will insert whatever the output is into where I put "res"

Comment: Actually, just do ```process.stdout.write("RESULT: "+```the function goes here```+"\n");```

Comment: Well, if you see anything in the console, then it should work